# Dealing with kernel panics in FreeBSD

Tags: freebsd, debug, kernel-panic

I'm regularly encountering a kernel panic on my FreeBSD 9 laptop.

I have not been able to fix the problem by updating my system to the current stable version (which I got from the ctm-svn), so how shall I go forth to find out the reason for this kernel panic and how to get rid of it?

I have the three files `info.N`, `core.txt.N` and `vmcore.N` that `savecore` writes to `/var/crash` during the boot process, where `info.N` contains something like

```
Dump header from device /dev/ada0p3
  Architecture: amd64
  Architecture Version: 2
  Dump Length: 289755136B (276 MB)
  Blocksize: 512
  Dumptime: Mon Feb  4 08:07:41 2013
  Hostname: hostname
  Magic: FreeBSD Kernel Dump
  Version String: FreeBSD 9.1-STABLE #4 r246115: Sat Feb  2 14:29:28 GMT 2013
    root@:/usr/obj/usr/src/sys/GENERIC
  Panic String: page fault
  Dump Parity: 2576771399
  Bounds: 3
  Dump Status: good
```

`core.txt.N` contains more context and `vmcore.N` is huge.

Comment: Do you already have dumps enabled? (If not, see  http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en/books/developers-handbook/kerneldebug.html  for instructions on how to do that).

Comment: Can you post the panic stack? Did you get a minidump?

Comment: I'd start by running a memory test like [memtest86+](http://www.memtest.org/) for a few hours. If you get any errors at all, it's a hardware or BIOS configuration problem.

Answer (score 1):

It is rare for software to cause a kernel panic these days. Often kernel panics they are hardware related. Possible culprits are:

- Bad memory
- voltage too low
- battery run down
- CPU temperature too high

(although usually a low battery should trigger a clean shutdown, and CPU overtemperature just switches the machine off)

You can analyze the crashdumps with `kgdb -n N`, where N is the dump number. If the crashes consistently happen at the same point/subsystem in the kernel, it is probably a software problem. If they happen in different places, it's probably hardware.

There are several monitoring programs for running under X in the ports collection, like `sysutils/conky`. Those can help you keep an eye on battery status, CPU temperature, core voltage et cetera.